# Slow speed of images being displayed in the GridView from SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, performance, gridview

Hi I have this peace of code. It is called on RowDataBound event of my gridview. I am inserting the images from the sql data source. However, the load speed of the gridview with the images in it especially on IE seems to be very slow is there some way to reduce the size of the images that are being parsed trough the SQL to reduce the load times.

I would be displaying only a smaller image of the original image, maybe thumbnail approach would solve some issues?

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.FindControl("bigImage");

                var dv = new DataView();
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataSource6.DataBind();
                    dv = SqlDataSource6.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
                    dt = dv.ToTable();
                    byte[] imageBig = BitConverter.GetBytes(2345);
                    int EntryId;


                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {

                        imageBig = (byte[])dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[4];
                        EntryId = (int)dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[3];
                        if (EntryId == id)
                        {   
                            img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBig);
                        }}}}
```

Comment: This should probably be done on code review

Comment: What is the size of the images? Because you are converting them to base64 and that can generate a lot of text in the html, slowing down the browsers.

Comment: The size varies it is up to 5mb allow upload on the site. the performance reduces significantly once bigger pictures are uploaded. Maybe creating a thumbnail could sort the issue as I am displaying only a smaller image of the original image?

Comment: Just using primary keys in SQL with images seems easier approach if there is a lot of entries, easier to track as well.

Comment: Yes, better use thumbnails. 5 mb in base64 is a bad idea.

Comment: adding thumbnails even worsen the performance maybe dealing with SQL and base64 strings should be avoided and its better just to fetch those images from the folder of the server? @VDWWD